# TypeError: t.toggleState is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am using this library:

```
https://revolution.themepunch.com/
```

For some reason this library is not working on my site anymore. It is supposed to show a slider, but nothing shows up.
Looking in the console I see:

```
TypeError: t.toggleState is not a function
```

I tried to find a solution and also changes to this version of jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Anybody knows where I should look?

****EDIT****

The site Im working on is:

```
http://fancyhomesolutions.com/index.html
```

In the console you should see the same error message. Tried it both on chrome and firefox. It is trying to execute this js-script:

```
http://revolution.themepunch.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js
```

Comment: Can you provide more code for us to help you?

Answer (score 1):

All Js files should be same version both extensions and Js files of revolution slider.
If your updating below extension files only, then you will get this conflict.

[image: extension and js files of revolution slider]